# Class extension not working - VSCode + PlatformIO + Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++, platformio

I've bumped into an issue, which is pretty weird to me, since it should work. I'm porting an esp8266 firmware to esp32, working with platformio in vscode.

The error I get

```
OpenSprinkler.cpp: In static member function 'static void OpenSprinkler::begin()':
OpenSprinkler.cpp:860:8: error: 'class IOEXP' has no member named 'set_pins_output_mode'
  drio->set_pins_output_mode();
```

This looks clear, but in the referred line (OpenSprinkler.cpp:860) the code looks like this:

```
    drio = new IOEXP_SR(255);
    drio->set_pins_output_mode();
```

And the header file for IOEXP_SR:

```
class IOEXP_SR : public IOEXP {
public:
  IOEXP_SR(uint8_t addr) { type = IOEXP_TYPE_SR; }
/*  void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t IOMode) { 
    if(IOMode!=OUTPUT) inputmask |= (1<<pin);
  }
  uint16_t i2c_read(uint8_t reg);*/
  void set_pins_output_mode() ;
  void i2c_write(uint16_t v);
private:
  uint8_t inputmask = 0;  // mask bits for input pins
};
```

Actual code for the function:

```
void IOEXP_SR::set_pins_output_mode(){
    // shift register setup
    // pinMode(PIN_SR_OE, OUTPUT);
    // pull shift register OE high to disable output
    // digitalWrite(PIN_SR_OE, HIGH);
    pinMode(IOEXP_SR_LATCH_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(IOEXP_SR_LATCH_PIN, HIGH);

    pinMode(IOEXP_SR_CLK_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(IOEXP_SR_CLK_PIN, HIGH);
    pinMode(IOEXP_SR_DATA_PIN,  OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(IOEXP_SR_DATA_PIN, LOW);
    
    #if defined(SEPARATE_MASTER_VALVE)
    // DEBUG_PRINTLN("Enabling separate master valve");
    pinMode(SEPARATE_MASTER_VALVE,OUTPUT);
    if ( STATION_LOGIC ) {
        digitalWrite(SEPARATE_MASTER_VALVE,LOW);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(SEPARATE_MASTER_VALVE,HIGH);
    }
    #endif
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Whatever you're asking about, c++ on Arduino isn't standard c++, it's a specific dialect and framework, and you should use tagging wiser and more specific here!

Comment: What are you missing? C++ polymorphism. As you downcasted IOEXP_SR* to IOEXP* you can only use interface for IOEXP and without polymorphism (virtual methods and its overrides) you can't call IOEXP_SR::method() from IOEXP::method()

Comment: @KIIV thx, I really forgot the virtual method in IOEXP...

Answer (score 0):

As @KIVV pointed out, I've forgotten to add the virtual method to IOEXP

```
class IOEXP {
public:
    IOEXP(uint8_t addr=255) { address = addr; type = IOEXP_TYPE_NONEXIST; }

    virtual void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t IOMode) { }
    virtual uint16_t i2c_read(uint8_t reg) { return 0xFFFF; }
    virtual void i2c_write(uint8_t reg, uint16_t v) { }
    // software implementation of shift register out
    virtual void shift_out(uint8_t plat, uint8_t pclk, uint8_t pdat, uint8_t v) { }
    virtual void set_pins_output_mode() { }
```